# No log data exists. Problem with View Cluster

Tags: abap

I need to create a View Cluster, but when I double-click on the "Field-dependence" button, I get this error:

> No log data exists

Here is the view cluster and the error message:

[image: view cluster and error No log data exists]

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the same issue with a completely valid view cluster, with exactly the same relationships (R and M). This valid view cluster was made of the standard views `V_T005` and `V_T005G` for the tables `T005`/countries and `T005G`/cities respectively, `T005G` has a foreign key for the country column to `T005`.

I couldn't find any satisfying answer in the Internet, nor in SAP support web site, so I debugged a little bit.

If the generation of field dependencies doesn't fail, there is no message added to the log, and if you had no previous error in previous executions, SAP tries to display the log anyway, and fails if there's no message, with the message BL223:

> No log data exists

You should simply ignore the message by pressing the ❌ red cross button in the top standard toolbar, there's a popup "Your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to cancel?" Click "No" and continue normally.

When you're finished with the changes, return to the "Header Entry" and press the button "Activate". Eventually you may get the error messages at this level.

Answer (score 0):

One question have u define field dependencies for both tables?

If so.

Then **u have to define only the relationship from the 2nd to 1st table only**.

Double click on field dependencies & **check**. no need to generate twice.